# Do while loop with Character input

Tags: c, char, do-while

I have written this simple program, which is supposed to calculate the factorial of a number entered by the user. The program should ask the user to stop or continue the  program in order to find the factorial of a new number.

since most of the time user don't pay attention to CapsLock the program should accept Y or y as an answer for yes. But every time I run this program and even though I enter Y/y , it gets terminated !

I googled and found out the problem could be due to `new line`character getting accepted with my character input so, I modified the scanf code from `scanf("%c", &choice);` to `scanf("%c ", &choice);` in order to accommodate the new line character , but my program is still getting terminated after accepting Y/y as input.

Here is the code . Please if possible let me know the best practices and methods to deal with these kinds of issues along with the required correction.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Disablewarning.h" // header file to disable s_secure warning in visual studio contains #pragma warning (disable : 4996) 

void main() {
    int factorial=1;//Stores the factorial value
    int i; //Counter
    char choice;//stores user choice to continue or terminte the program

        do {//Makes sure the loop isn't terminated until the user decides
            do{
                printf("Enter the no whose factorial you want to calculate:\t");
                scanf("%d", &i);
            } while (i<0);

        if (i == 0) //calculates 0!
            factorial = 1;
        else {//Calculates factorial for No greater than 1;
            while (i > 0) {
                factorial = factorial*i;
                i--;
            }
        }

        printf("\nThe factorialof entered no is :\t%d", factorial);//prints the final result

        printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)?");
        scanf("%c ", &choice);

    } while (choice =="y" || choice =="Y"); // Checks if user wants to continue 

}
```

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm running this code in visual studio 2015.

Comment: `} while (choice =="y" || choice =="Y");` -> `} while (choice =='y' || choice =='Y');`

Comment: `"Y"` is a pointer to `char`, but `'Y'` is a mere `char`.

Comment: @Biffen it was in recommendation . Should i remove the tag ?

Comment: `void main()` -> UB + deprecated in C. Which language is it, C or C++?? Pick one!

Comment: I removed the C++ code! It's in C.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: @xenteros I tried to be as thorough as I can be . what else do I need to add ?

Comment: @RishiShukla the example must be **minimal**. I know there are 10 types of programmers - one start curly braces in the same line, the others in a new one, but in terms of asking on [so] please minimize number of lines of your code to avoid the need of scrolling.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I made the change from `(choice =="y" || choice =="Y"); -> (choice =='y' || choice =='Y');` still the same result. Program exits even after taking y/Y as input.

Comment: alternatively the example should be [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable)](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: did you read the compiler warnings?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, Sir ! there were no warnings.

Comment: @xenteros desired behaviour is mentioned in the question. The program should keep calculating the factorial of the number till the time user decides he doesn't want to enter any more values. Let me know if you expect a different answer , I believe I'm not able to understand you very well.

Comment: are you sure? Compile with `-Werr -Wall -Wpedantic`. I'm sure any compiler will shout at you in the line `choice =="y" || choice =="Y"`

Comment: If you get no warnings, you need a better compiler.  With `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wpedantic`, it tells me **return type of `main()` is not `int`** and **comparison between pointer and integer** and **comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior**.  All of those should be fixed before you start debugging.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc here is the screenshot of visual studio warning window with the same unedited code . (http://imgur.com/a/K5S5c).

Comment: @RishiShukla in MSVC use [`/W4 /Wall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx). Your code will provide lots of warnings like `3:11: error: '::main' must return 'int' In function 'int main()': 28:23: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress] 28:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] 28:39: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress] 28:39: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]` http://cpp.sh/5otsi

Comment: In C you'll get http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5qIet28ycmvGmuCQ `error: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]; In function 'main': error: comparison between pointer and integer } while (choice =="y" || choice =="Y"); warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]; error: comparison between pointer and integer
     } while (choice =="y" || choice =="Y"); warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify your scanf like following:

```
printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ");
scanf(" %c", &choice); //You should add the space before %c, not after
```

also you should use:

```
} while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'); // Checks if user wants to continue
```

NOTE:
Simple quote `'` is used for characters and double quote `"` is used for string

Comment: Thank You !! It worked as expected  :) Please let me know why this one is working but not the previous one `"%c "` , and also point me to the articles/links where I can read more about this behaviour .  If possible please let me know best techniques  and methods to deal with this kind of situation . Thank you once again .

Comment: in that situation you can check the input value with `scanf` using a simple `printf()`

Answer (score 2):

Your second-last line has a string literal `"y"`, which should be a character literal i.e. `'y'`:

```
 } while (choice =="y" || choice =="Y");
```

This should be:

```
 } while (choice =='y' || choice =='Y');
```

Also, your `scanf()` doesn't consume whitespace.  Add a space before `%c` to make it ignore newlines or other spaces:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

Comment: @George The answer is still true, though.

Comment: see above i made change it working for me now add space after %c as below 

scanf(" %c", &choice);

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following even after the correction there are still some bugs in the code
In your code if you type 'Y' and recalculate a factorial it gives wrong answer as

> int factorial is already loaded with the previous value

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int calculateFactorial(int i);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char choice;

    do{
        printf("Enter the no whose factorial you want to calculate:\t");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        printf("\n The factorial of entered no is :\t %d", calculateFactorial(i));
        printf("\n Do you want to continue (Y/N)?");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'); 
    return 0;
}

int calculateFactorial(int i) {
    int factorial = 1;
    if (i == 0){
        factorial = 1;
    }else {
        while (i > 0){
            factorial = factorial*i;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: "I'm a beginner in programming and I'm running this code in visual studio 2015" .I haven't read the function call part yet. Thanks, though.

Comment: no problem its ok if you don't want to use function for now as you are a beginner , so you reset the variable int factorial in the do{factorial = 1; }while(---)

Comment: Yaa !! I made that correction as soon as the loop started working as expected !! :)